# Is it possible to partially get/modify a field?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm setting up to gather long time statistics. It will be recorded in little blocks that I'm planning to stick all into one TEXT field, latest first.. sorta like this

```
[date:03.01.2016,data][date:02.01.2016,data][date:01.01.2016,data]...
```

it will be more frequent than that (just a sample) but should remain small enough to keep recording for decades, yet big enough to make me want to optimize it.

I'm looking for 2 things

1. Can you append to the front of a field in mysql?
2. Can you read the field partially, just the first 100 characters for example?

The blocks will be fixed length so I can accurately estimate how many characters I need to download to display statistics for X time period.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea in so many ways.  First, if you really plan to append thousands or more of these timestamps, then you could easily exceed the space in the column.  Also, while it possible to simulate appending by updating the old value, this also isn't so nice.  A better option would be to place each timestamp token into its own _record_.

Comment: When someone asks you to get statistics for some period - what will you do? Parse sting?

Comment: do you think you are doing the server, user, and storage any favors by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your two questions is "yes":

```
update t
    set field = concat($newval, field)
    where id = $id;
```

And:

```
select left(field, 100)
from t
where id = $id;
```

(These assume that you have multiple rows in the table.)

That said, you method of storing the data is absolutely not the right thing to do in a relational database.

Presumably, you want a table that looks something like this:

```
create table t (
    tId int auto_increment primary key,
    creationDate date,
    data <something>
);
```

(This may be more complicated if `data` should be multiple columns.)

Then you insert into the table:

```
insert into t(createDate, data)
    select $date, $data;
```

And you can fetch the most recent row:

```
select t.*
from t
order by tId desc
limit 1;
```

All of these are just examples, because your question doesn't give a complete picture of the data.

Comment: Gordon is right. Putting lots of concatenated data into a `TEXT` field in a RDMS is like using a hammer to put in the screws in your new furniture. It will make a mess, and your furniture will fall apart as soon as you start using it.

Comment: its a bit more tricky then that, I collect the data on thousands of different objects (which are the rows in a table) and given that the statistics will only make sense in the context of the object, I figured sticking them into the object as a field would be quicker and generally more efficient than creating a separate table for them

Comment: @user81993 . . . You need an `ObjectData` table with one row per object and one row per data.  You should not be putting the data into a single concatenated field.  That is simply the wrong approach.